# How do I split a string into a list without removing the delimiter

Tags: python

I have a string `'[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]'`

I want to split it into a list like `['[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]')
([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0])
```

This also parses the inner lists, which you might not want to.

It's not that complicated to convert the inner lists back to strings if you desire:

```
>>> [str(inner) for inner in ast.literal_eval('[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]')]
['[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not produce the desired result

Comment: @JCaesar I didn't include the rest of the code initially as it was trivial, but I added it now

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression like this:

```
import re
re.findall('\[.*?\]',  '[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]')
```

which produces the result:

```
['[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]']
```

Note to use of '*?' in the pattern to make it non-greedy (otherwise it would just match everything between first [ and last ].

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this:

```
    import ast

    L = '[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]'
    O = [str(p) for p in ast.literal_eval(L)]
    print(O)
```

**Output:**

```
['[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex and `re.split`:

```
import re

s = '[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]'
out = re.split('(?<=]),\s*', s)
```

output: `['[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]']`

Comment: note that your output isn't the desired result. (leading ' ' in second and third element).

Comment: absolutely right, fixed it, thanks @ChristianSloper

Answer (score 0):

It also handles `[` or `]` appearing in character elements.

```py
import re

print(re.split(r"(?<=]), *?(?=\[)", '[0, 0, 0, "[", "]"], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]'))

# ['[0, 0, 0, "[", "]"]', '[0, 0, 0]', '[0, 0, 0]']
```